# Javascript not importing variable from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

formFields.js

```
export const invoiceFormFields = [
    {label: 'First Name', name: 'firstName', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Last Name', name: 'lastName', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Deliverables', name: 'deliverables', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Email', name: 'email', type: 'email'},
    {label: 'Amount', name: 'amount', type: 'number'}
]
```

InvoiceForm.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { NewInvoiceContext } from '../../contexts/newInvoice.context'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {
    Typography,
    Paper,
    TextField,
    makeStyles,
    Button,
    CssBaseline,
} from '@material-ui/core'

import { invoiceFormFields } from './formFields'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    title: {
        marginBottom: '1rem',
    },
    form: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    formInput: {
        marginTop: '1rem',
    },
    formButtons: {
        display: 'flex',
        marginTop: '2rem',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
}))

const InvoiceForm = ({ history }) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const {formDetails, handleFormChange, handleShowReview} = useContext(NewInvoiceContext)

    const newInvoiceFields = invoiceFormFields.map(({ label, name, type }) => (
        <TextField
            key={name}
            label={label}
            name={name}
            className={classes.formInput}
            type={type}
            required
            onChange={handleFormChange}
            value={formDetails[name]}
        />
    ))


}

export default InvoiceForm
```

I'm getting the error

Attempted import error: './formFields' does not contain a default export (imported as 'formFields').

From what I can see I'm exporting and importing correctly - does anyone have any ideas what could be happening here?

Thanks

Comment: That error isn't coming from that code, it sounds like you have another `import` somewhere (or a stale error message). You're not trying to use a default export in any `import` related to `formFields`.

Comment: do you have rule in eslint for import export?

Comment: Hey, I just added links to github for the code - does that help at all? Thanks in advance @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @MitchellCartwright - Unfortunately, the way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) and [mcve].

Comment: (Just for the avoidance of doubt: You're right, the export you've shown from `formFields` and the import of it are just fine. Depending on your environment, file extensions may be necessary (e.g., `from "./formFields.js"` rather than just `from "./formFields"`), but the error message doesn't seem to relate to that.)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder - will troubleshoot to see if it is a linting issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: I hope you find it! :-)

Comment: Are you using react-docgen?

Comment: I hate to say it, but you might consider deleting the question while you're continuing your debugging, and then reopening (or reposting) it once you can include an [mcve]. The question is currently attracting a bunch of low-quality answers... :-(

Answer (score -1):

I suppose this would make it work.

```
export const invoiceFormFields = [
    {label: 'First Name', name: 'firstName', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Last Name', name: 'lastName', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Deliverables', name: 'deliverables', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Email', name: 'email', type: 'email'},
    {label: 'Amount', name: 'amount', type: 'number'}
];

export default {
    invoiceFormFields,
}
```

```
import { invoiceFormFields } from './formFields';
```

Comment: That exports an object with an `invoiceFormFields` property as the default export; your named import at the end can't import a *property* of an object exported as a default export. :-) Again, as said in more than one comment on the question, the `export` and `import` shown **are fine**. We can't answer the question in its current form, because the code shown doesn't cause the problem described.